# Pointer to the start of an object (C++)

Tags: c++, casting, rtti, typeid

I need a way to get a pointer to the start of an object in C++. This object is used inside a template so it can be any type (polymorphic or not) and could potentially be an object that uses multiple inheritance.

I found [this article](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/450) which describes a way to do it (see the section called "Dynamic Casts") using typeid and a dynamic_cast to void* in the case that T is a polymorphic type.

This works perfectly well on MSVC, however on GCC (4.x) it seems to fall on its arse and spits out a compiler error when it is used with a non-polymorphic type.

Does anyone know a way to:

- Make GCC behave itself, and evaluate typeid correctly
- Or another way to do this, that will compile on GCC

Below is the code I am currently using to try and achieve this.

```
template <typename T>
void* dynamicCastToVoidPtr(T *const ptr)
{
    // This is done using a separate function to avoid a compiler error on some 
    // compilers about non-polymorphic types when calling startOfObject
    return dynamic_cast<void*>(ptr);
}

template <typename T>
void* startOfObject(T *const ptr)
{
    // In cases of multiple inheritance, a pointer may point to an offset within 
    // another object
    // This code uses a dynamic_cast to a void* to ensure that the pointer value 
    // is the start of an object and not some offset within an object
    void *start = static_cast<void*>(ptr);
    if(start)
        typeid(start = dynamicCastToVoidPtr(ptr), *ptr);
    return start;
}

template <typename T>
void doSomethingWithInstance(T *const instance)
{
    // Here is where I need to get a void* to the start of the object
    // You can think of this as the deleteInstance function of my memory pool
    // where the void* passed into freeMemory should point to the
    // start of the memory that the memory pool returned previously
    void *start = startOfObject(instance);
    if(start)
        allocator->freeMemory(start);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: $10/5 states- "[Note: A base class subobject might have a layout (3.7) different from the layout of a most derived object of the same type. A base class subobject might have a polymorphic behavior (12.7) different from the polymorphic behavior of a most derived object of the same type. A base class subobject may be of zero size (clause 9); however, two subobjects that have the same class type and that belong to the same most derived object must not be allocated at the same address (5.10). ]"

Comment: What should happen with `struct point { int x; int y; }; point *p = new point(); doSomethingWithInstance(&p->x);`?

Comment: Logan; that would be an invalid use of the function. It should only be used with instances that have been allocated on the heap.

Comment: Why would one want to do this?  I'm just interested - it sounds purely evil to me.

Comment: @MrD So if I have to know how to use the function correctly already, is it so unreasonable to pass in the start of the object from the word go? Remember, if I want to destruct the object, I need the "start" of it anyway, calling a destructor in the "middle" of the object is a bad idea. I think the appropriate approach here is to use your allocator's meta-data to find the start of the _allocation_, given the pointer into the middle of an allocation, if you want to support that sort of usage at all.

Comment: @Logan am I missing something or isn't virtual destruction designed to cope with this?

Comment: @Will Yes, a virtual destructor would cope with this.

@Logan The freeMemory function can be thought of as the C free function, not a delete operator. The reason I need this to work correctly it because as well as using it for the memory allocator, I also use it for a smart pointer implementation based on the article I linked to. The reason I used the memory allocator as an example is because it is a simpler use case.

Comment: "The freeMemory function can be thought of as the C free function, not a delete operator", this is my point. If all you're doing is freeing memory, the allocator has enough information to find the start of the allocation without needing to know the start of the object, you can find the start of an allocation from an arbitrary pointer to the middle of it (because you need to track this information anyway just for the purposes of book keeping in the allocator).

Comment: Yes, I can (and do) do that in this case for a sanity check. However I am also using this function in a smart pointer implementation based on the article I linked to in my question. In that situation I can't work around the issue since I have no 'book-keeping' to look through so ultimately I need this function to work somehow.

Comment: @Will The answer as to why I want to do it is in part in the article I link to, since I use a similar repository system for my smart pointers as the article describes. Since the map uses the memory locations as keys, I need to always get the correct start location, even in the case of multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107948/test-whether-a-class-is-polymorphic) that lets me work out at compile time if a type is polymorphic and I can then use this with template specialisation to use the correct type of cast. Apparently this method might break if the compiler adds padding between sub-objects, but I can hopefully add some compile time asserts on some known cases to catch that. It does compile and run correctly on both MSVC and GCC.

This is the code to work out if a type is polymorphic.

```
#define SIMPLE_POLYMORPHIC(TYPE, POLYMORPHIC)   \
    template <>                                 \
    struct IsPolymorphic<TYPE>                  \
    {                                           \
        static const bool value = POLYMORPHIC;  \
    };

template <typename T>
struct IsPolymorphic
{
    struct Derived : public T { virtual ~Derived(); };
    static const bool value = (sizeof(Derived) == sizeof(T));
};

SIMPLE_POLYMORPHIC(int, false);
SIMPLE_POLYMORPHIC(unsigned int, false);
// ... do this for all intrinsic or non-derivable types
```

The code to perform the casting based on whether the type is polymorphic.

```
template <typename T, bool isPolymorphic = IsPolymorphic<T>::value>
struct StartOfObject
{
    static void* getStart(T *const ptr)
    {
        return static_cast<void*>(ptr);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct StartOfObject<T, true>
{
    static void* getStart(T *const ptr)
    {
        if(ptr)
            return dynamic_cast<void*>(ptr);
        return NULL;
    }
};
```

And a test case for it.

```
#define CLASS_STUFF(CLASS)      \
    public:                     \
        CLASS() {}              \
        virtual ~CLASS() {}     \
        int m_##CLASS;

class A
{
    CLASS_STUFF(A);
};

class B : public A
{
    CLASS_STUFF(B);
};

class C
{
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << IsPolymorphic<A>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << IsPolymorphic<B>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << IsPolymorphic<C>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << IsPolymorphic<int>::value << std::endl;

    StartOfObject<A>::getStart(new A());
    StartOfObject<B>::getStart(new B());
    StartOfObject<C>::getStart(new C());
    StartOfObject<int>::getStart(new int());

    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact error message by gcc is

> **error**: cannot dynamic_cast `&n` (of type `struct N*`) to type `void*` (source type is not polymorphic)

This could be handled by using `boost::is_polymorphic` in combination with `boost::enable_if` and `boost::disable_if`, unfortunately gcc chokes with the obvious approach, so here is the workaround:

```
template <class T>
void* address_of_impl(T* p, boost::enable_if< boost::is_polymorphic<T>, int >)
{
  return dynamic_cast<void*>(p);
}

template <class T>
void* address_of_impl(T* p, ...) { return static_cast<void*>(p); }

template <class T>
void* address_of(T* p) { return address_of_impl(p, 0); }
```

Where we use SFINAE at our advantage (the ellipsis is always considered last in overload resolution so the compiler first attempts to use the `dynamic_cast` version which fails for non polymorphic types because of `enable_if`).

I've test it on gcc 3.4 and it passed. I'm investigating in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491848/enable-if-disable-if-combination-provokes-an-ambiguous-call) why using `disable_if` instead of `...` doesn't work.

**EDIT**:

and it was a simple typo (forgot the `::type` bit):

```
template <class T>
typename boost::enable_if< boost::is_polymorphic<T>, void* >::type
address_of(T* p) { return dynamic_cast<void*>(p); }

template <class T>
typename boost::disable_if< boost::is_polymorphic<T>, void* >::type
address_of(T* p) { return static_cast<void*>(p); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some investigation, and you *may* have found a bug in GCC here; I would [report it](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/).  However, there may be some rule I can't find that says that the template function on the left side of the comma operator does need to be instantiated in this case, even though the overall expression is not evaluated; in that case the technique in the article is just wrong.

I suggest you see if [boost::type_traits::is_polymorphic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_polymorphic.html) can be made to work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this code is part of a library and I am trying to avoid a required dependency on Boost.

Comment: You could just read boost/type_traits/is_polymorphic.hpp and figure out what it's doing and do it yourself :)  (Good luck with that, though, Boost is many things but comprehensible ain't one of them.)

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably have a look at that. If I could tell if a type was polymorphic at compile time then I could use template specialisation to solve the problem instead.

Comment: There is an extractor tool on boostpro which cleans up the boost headers (removes anything not necessary for your compiler).