# enable_if + disable_if combination provokes an ambiguous call

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, enable-if

While trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488048/pointer-to-the-start-of-an-object-c) I wanted to suggest the use of `enable_if` + `disable_if` to allow the overload of a method based on the fact that a type was (or not) polymorphic.

So I created a small test file:

```
template <class T>
void* address_of(T* p,
                 boost::enable_if< boost::is_polymorphic<T> >* dummy = 0)
{ return dynamic_cast<void*>(p); }

template <class T>
void* address_of(T* p,
                 boost::disable_if< boost::is_polymorphic<T> >* dummy = 0)
{ return static_cast<void*>(p); }

struct N { int x; };


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  N n;
  std::cout << address_of(&n) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

which seems quite tame.

However gcc (3.4 ...) choke on this:

> test.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)`:
>   test.cpp:29: error: call of overloaded `address_of(N*)` is ambiguous
>   test.cpp:17: note: candidates are: `void* address_of(T*,
>   boost::enable_if<boost::is_polymorphic<T>, void>*)` [with T = N]
>   test.cpp:20: note:                 `void* address_of(T*,
>   boost::disable_if<boost::is_polymorphic<T>, void>*)` [with T = N]

It seems rather clear to my human mind which overload should be used here. I mean it seems clear that I have defined an alternative and only one function can be used at a time... and I would have thought that SFINAE would take care of invalidating the unnecessary overload.

I patched it up by using `...` (ellipsis) instead of `disable_if` and requiring a dummy second argument... but I am still interested in why the compiler choke on this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler choked because you forgot the trailing `::type` on `enable_if` and `disable_if`. The templates are always defined; it is just that the member `type` is present if and only if the expression is `true` (for `enable_if`) or `false` (for `disable_if`).

```
template <class T>
void* address_of(T* p,
                 typename boost::enable_if< boost::is_polymorphic<T> >::type* dummy = 0)
{ return dynamic_cast<void*>(p); }

template <class T>
void* address_of(T* p,
                 typename boost::disable_if< boost::is_polymorphic<T> >::type* dummy = 0)
{ return static_cast<void*>(p); }
```

Without the trailing `::type`, your function templates just create overloads that take pointers to instances of `enable_if` or `disable_if` as the second parameter. With the trailing `::type`, the templates either create an overload with a second parameter of type `void*`, or the overload is removed (i.e. the desired behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

Using the "return type" version of enable_if works in 3.4.4: `gcc version 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)`

```
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_polymorphic.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
typename boost::enable_if< boost::is_polymorphic<T>, void* >::type
address_of(T* p)
{ return dynamic_cast<void*>(p); }

template <class T>
typename boost::disable_if< boost::is_polymorphic<T>, void* >::type
address_of(T* p)
{ return static_cast<void*>(p); }

struct N { int x; };


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  N n;
  std::cout << address_of(&n) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```