# Decent way to disallow virtual functions due to placement new usage

Tags: c++

What would be a decent approach to check at compile/run-time that a particular struct/class does not have any virtual functions. This check is required in order to ensure the proper byte alignment when doing **placement new**.

Having so much as a single virtual function will shift the entire data by a *vtable* pointer size, which will completely mess things up in conjunction with the placement new operator.

---

**Some more details:** I need something that works across all major compiler and platforms, e.g. VS2005, VC++10, GCC 4.5, and Sun Studio 12.1 on top of Windows, Linux, and Solaris.

Something that *is guaranteed to work* with the following scenario should suffice:

```
struct A { char c; void m(); };
struct B : A { void m(); };
```

Should someone decide to make this change:

```
struct A { char c; virtual void m(); };
struct B : A { void m(); };
```

It would be great to see a compile-time error that says `struct A must not contain virtual functions.`

Comment: Placement new works just fine with virtual classes. The placement new operator will be given the actual size of the class (including the vtable pointer). You should be able to use any allocator with it, so long as it would have aligned the original class correctly.

Comment: @Nicol: And sized the buffer with `sizeof` rather than by guessing.

Comment: @Nicol i am working with raw data -- there is no room for a vtable pointer

Comment: @Nick What do you mean by "raw data"? If it's raw data, then it shouldn't be a class, correct? Since classes are structured data.

Comment: I am using the placement new operator to initialize an object on top of raw data.

Comment: Placement new overwrites the storage with a new object. If you are using placement new you shouldn't care what the raw data is as you are overwriting it. If you want to read the raw data _as if_ it were the data for a class you just need to perform a `void*` to `AClass*` cast. Placement new would be incorrect for this use case.

Comment: @Charles good point -- one amendmend though: placement new overwrite the storage only if fields are initialized at construction time -- which are not in my case. The vtable pointer issues remains either when doing a cast or a zero-initialization class placement new.

Comment: Found a really weird is_polymorphic<> trait hack in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107948/test-whether-a-class-is-polymorphic

Comment: Thanks, Tony -- interesting approach, though apparently less trustworthy

Comment: The placement form of `operator new` doesn't do anything to the underlying storage but it is permissible for a placement `new` expression to do something with the storage - such as set it to zero or a debug value - between the time the pointer is returned by `operator new` and the time the new object is initialized. If you are relying on the values in the raw storage making it through to the new object just because they aren't explicitly initialized then you are relying on an implementation detail.

Comment: @Charles right -- I understand. Casting to void* seems to be the better option indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost certainly doing something wrong.

However, given that you have decided to do something wrong, you don't want to know if your tpe has no virtual functions.  You want to know if it is okay to treat your type as an array of bytes.

In C++03, is your type POD?  As luck would have it, there's a trait for that, aptly named `is_pod<T>`.  This is provided by Boost/TR1 in C++03, although it requires a relatively modern compiler [gcc > 4.3, MSVC > 8, others I don't know].

In C++11, you can ease up your requirements by asking if your type is trivially copiable. Again, there's a trait for that: `is_trivially_copyable<T>`.

In either case, there is also `is_polymorphic<T>`, but as I said, that's really not what you want anyhow.  If you are using an older compiler, it does have the advantage of working out of the box if you get it from Boost; it performs the `sizeof` test mentioned elsewhere, rather than simply reporting `false` for all user defined types as is the case with `is_pod`.

No matter what, you'd better be 120% sure your constructor is a noop; that's not something that can be verified.

---

I just saw your edit.  Of what you listed, Sun Studio is the only one that might not have the necessary intrinsics for these traits to work.  gcc and MSVC have both had them for several years now.

Comment: Thanks, good pointers. In for a penny in for a pound, any good way to check the constructor is a noop?

Comment: Just since you wrote "...you'd better be 120%": in plain C/C++ there is no such thing as an "array of bytes". There are no bytes, only characters. Therefore, all memory-functions possibly needed to do persistence are declared with `void`-arguments. For example, on some machines it could be that `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`. It's good to know that when storing objects ;-)

Answer (score 7):

There are facilities and tricks (depending on the version of C++ you are using) to get the proper alignment for a class.

In C++0x, the `alignof` command is similar to `sizeof` but returns the required alignment instead.

In C++03, the first thing to note is that the size is a multiple of the alignment, because elements need be contiguous in an array. This means that using the size as the alignment is over-zealous (and may waste space) but works fine. With some trickery you can get a better value:

```
template <typename T>
struct AlignHelper
{
  T t;
  char c;
};

template <typename T>
struct Alignment
{
  static size_t const diff = sizeof(AlignHelper<T>) - sizeof(T);
  static size_t const value = (diff != 0) ? diff : sizeof(T);
};
```

This little helper gives a correct alignment as a compile-time constant (suitable for template programming therefore). It may be larger than the minimal alignment required (*).

Normally though it should be fine to use placement new, unless you are actually using it on a "raw buffer". In this case, the size of the buffer should be determined with the following formula:

```
// C++03
char buffer[sizeof(T) + alignof(T) - 1];
```

Or you should make use of C++0x facilities:

```
// C++0x
std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> buffer;
```

Another trick to ensure a "right" alignment for virtual tables it to make use of the union:

```
// C++03 and C++0x
union { char raw[sizeof(T)]; void* aligner; } buffer;
```

The `aligner` parameter guarantees that the `buffer` is correctly aligned for pointers, and thus for virtual tables pointers as well.

**EDIT**: Additional explanations as suggested by @Tony.

(*) How does this work ?

To understand it we need to delve into the memory representation of a class. Each subelement of a class has its own alignment requirement, so for example:

```
struct A { int a; char b; int c; };

+----+-+---+----+
| a  |b|xxx| c  |
+----+-+---+----+
```

Where `xxx` denotes padding added so that `c` is suitably aligned.

What is the alignment of `A` ? Generally speaking, it is the stricter alignment of the subelements, so here, the alignment of `int` (which is often `4` since `int` is often a `32` bits integral).

To "guess" the alignment of an arbitrary type, we thus "trick" the compiler by using the `AlignHelper` template. Remember that `sizeof(AlignHelper<T>)` must be a multiple of the alignment because types should be laid out contiguously in an array, thus we hope our type will be padded after the `c` attribute, and the alignment will be the size of `c` (`1` by definition) plus the size of the padding.

```
// AlignHelper<T>
+----------------+-+---+
|        t       |c|xxx|
+----------------+-+---+

// T
+----------------+
|        t       |
+----------------+
```

When we do `sizeof(AlignHelper<T>) - sizeof(T)` we get this difference. Surprisingly though, it could be `0`.

The issue comes from the fact that if there is some padding (unused bytes) at the end of `T`, then a smart compiler could decide to stash `c` there, and thus the difference of size would be `0`.

We could, obviously, try to recursively increase the size of `c` attribute (using a char array), until we finally get a non-zero difference. In which case we would get a "tight" alignment, but the simplest thing to do is to bail out and use `sizeof(T)`, since we already know it is a multiple of the alignment.

Finally, there is no guarantee that the alignment we get with this method is the alignment of `T`, we get a multiple of it, but it could be bigger, since `sizeof` is implementation dependent and a compiler could decide to align all types on power of 2 boundaries, for example.

Comment: +1 for covering a lot of ground well.  "It may be larger than the minimal alignment required." is true - I can see why, but given it's probably the most relevant part of your answer it would be nice to explain the "tightness" of the alignments produced....

Comment: @Tony: I didn't want to delve into memory representation here, because I am not so comfortable with it (and the optimizations the compilers might use). If you feel comfortable with the topic, I would welcome a primer :) or I can give it a try and hope people will correct me if I am wrong, I guess.

Comment: @Tony: edited, I would be more comfortable if it was reviewed though.

Comment: @Matthieu: hmmm... now I look more carefully, the extra "c" element is always at `offset(sizeof(T))`, never packed in more tightly even if the elements in `T` are say a 4-byte aligned type and a `char`.  This forces `sizeof(AlignHelper)` up to the next multiple of the required alignment.  So, maybe you were wrong in saying "It may be larger than the minimal alignment required.", and I was wrong in thinking you were right?  Can you find any way this can't work correctly?

Comment: @Tony: I think the compiler is allowed to 1/ use the unused bytes at the end of `t` (if any) to stash `c`, 2/ provide a `sizeof` that is actually larger than what we expect.

Comment: @Matthieu: 1/ that's disturbing... means a lot of memset/memcpy type operations using the type and sizeof would affect `c` too... consequences for read/write over object data too... I should check the Standard re that - will reply if I find anything; 2/ yes true - silly me - might e.g. align all structs to 4 byte boundaries just as a matter of course, even though the data types only need 1 or 2. Cheers.

Comment: @Tony: I would be very interested if you find anything wrt 1/. I have not myself (yet) and it is my main concern here. I know gcc have a "pack" attribute that could mess with this, but it is an extension.

Answer (score 3):

> What would be a decent approach to
>   check at compile/run-time that a
>   particular struct/class does not have
>   any virtual functions

```
template<typename T>
struct Is_Polymorphic
{
  struct Test : T { virtual ~Test() = 0; };
  static const bool value = (sizeof(T) == sizeof(Test));
};
```

Above `class` can help you to check if the [given class is polymorphic or not](http://www.ideone.com/xFFxN) **at compile time**. [Note: `virtual` inheritance also have a vtable included]

Comment: +1 Thanks for the effort -- this is quite clever and seems to work as a run-time check. How exactly would you use this trigger a compile-time error? Or some compile-time behavior.

Comment: @Nick, this is infact can be used as a compile time check also. (you can put some smart `typedef` to allow/disallow based on this.)

Comment: Is it safe to rely on the empty base class optimisation for this? Not sure it'll work portably across compilers and compiler command-line switches.  Also, a class *could* have virtual functions but no virtual destructor... though it's highly questionable practice.

Comment: @Tony, When we declare an `interface` inside C++; it generally contains pure `virtual` methods and no data members. Your point is also interesting.

Comment: re "interfaces", agreed - but that doesn't guarantee that inheriting from the interface won't increase the size of the derived object.  With very early C++ compilers, it was normal for every object to have a distinct address - including base classes (whether interfaces or not) and subobjects.  The "empty base class optimisation" became a sanctioned but AFAIK not required way to space-optimise that away.  Still, this approach is taken by boost and GCC... must be highly even if not guaranteed portable :-).

Answer (score 2):

`dynamic_cast` is only allowed for `polymorphic classes`, so you can utilize that for a compile time check.

Comment: A very good idea -- that means I should create a subclass and try to cast to it using `dynamic_cast` -- would that work?

Comment: I guess Nick wants a check that generates a true or false, distinct numbers or whatever, rather than a compile time error for non-polymorphic classes...?

Comment: Actually a compiler error would be just as good (as said in my original post) -- in order to warn the developer

Comment: Oh... super then... sorry I missed that in the Q.  +1 for Als.

Comment: @Nick, we can have a compile time check rather than generating error for checking if the class contains a vtable or not. See my answer.

Comment: Come to think of it, not sure how `dynamic_cast` can be used *not* to generate a compile-error when the class is non-polymorphic...

Comment: @Nick: You cannot. `dynamic_cast` needs classes to be polymorphic or it will always result in compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Use is_pod type trait from tr1?

Comment: Only works for a limited number of compilers. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_pod.html That page is a bit out of date though, try it out.

Comment: This is compile time and can be combined with static_assert. There is a drawback - being a POD means not only no virtual functions but also no constructors/destructors AFAIR. But given a question I assume placement new is used to put structure in raw memory (for example shared memory) and then checking that the structure is a POD makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature for you to determine whether a class has virtual functions are not.

Comment: I also missed that Nick's happy for the compilation to fail otherwise, which makes Als answer legit.  Cheers.

Comment: @Tony, there is a way to check at compile time if the class is having vtable or not. See my answer.

Comment: Found a trait hack here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107948/test-whether-a-class-is-polymorphic